# How to create an autocomplete textbox in register page - Drupal 6

Tags: 6, users, ajax

Consider I am doing a registration form with the following fields.

```
1. Name

2. Email

3. City
```

Here the city should be auto complete.

I created the city field with the help of content profile module in order to add more fields in future.

**Now how can i make the "City" text box auto complete.**

**How can i store the records in the table ?**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There's a full example for Drupal 6 here: [Textfield that uses autocomplete][1]. The code will probably be useful to people on this site as well so I'll post i here:

*The following is based on a module with the name: 'cities'*

In your form function:

```
$form['city'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'City',
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'cities/autocomplete',
);
```

In your module file:

```
function cities_menu(){
  // path with autocomplete function for cities
  $items['cities/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Autocomplete for cities',
    'page callback' => '_cities_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('use autocomplete'),  //or whatever permission makes sense
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Also in your module file:

```
function _cities_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();
  //search table `cities` for cities that begin with the letters the user enters in the form
  $result = db_query_range("SELECT city FROM {cities} WHERE LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER('%s%')", $string, 0, 10);
  // add matches to $matches
  while ($data = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $matches[$data->city] = check_plain($data->city);
  }
 print drupal_to_js($matches);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Autocomplete Widgets for Text and Number Fields](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets), I use it for this purpose and it works great.

> This module adds 3 autocomplete widgets for CCK fields of type Text
>   and Number.
>
> - Autocomplete for allowed values list: `... snip ...`
> - Autocomplete for existing field data: This widget can be used for Text only and it takes candidate values from existing values in the
>     database for that field.
> - (7.x only) Autocomplete for predefined suggestions: `... snip ...`